# Is $V$ a vector space in this case?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This shows up in the exercise of Halmos's book of Linear Algebra.

Let $P$ be the set of all polynomials, with complex coefficients, in a variable $t$. Let $V$ be a subset of $P$, consisting of vectors(polynomials) $x$ for which $x(t)=x(1-t)$ for all $t$. The question asks me to decide if $V$ is a vector space. I'm not sure if I understand the given equation. Can somebody explain this?

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? Note that calling $V$ a "subspace" implies that $V$ is a vector space (which may or may not be true).

Comment: For instance, if $x(t)=t$, then $x\notin V$, since, for instance $x(0)=0$ and $x(1-0)=1\ne x(0)$. But if $x(t)=4t^2-4t+1$, then $x\in V$, since $x(1-t)=x(t)$, for every number $t$.

Comment: It should be a subset. Somehow I don't understand what $x(t)=x(1-t)$ means...

Comment: The equation $x(t) = x(1-t)$ means that if you are given a polynomial, say $x(t) = t^2+1$, then the polynomial $x(1-t) = (1-t)^2 + 1 = t^2 - 2t + 2$ should be the same polynomial. Note that every constant polynomial has this form, and there are other non-trivial examples like $x(t) = t(1-t)$.

Comment: Ahh, okay thanks for the explanation. My dumb brain interprets $x(1-t)$ as the multiplication..

Comment: @able20 It might help if you call the polynomial $p$ instead? I also interpreted as multiplication on first reading, because $x$ is often a scalar.

Comment: That makes sense. The book calls it $x$, and that's why I was confused

Comment: From where scalars are taken? $\mathbb{R} $ or $ \mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: $V$ is a subset of $P$, which is a complex vector space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can substitute $t = 1/2+y$ to get $x(1/2+y) = x(1/2 - y)$. Thus $x(t)$ is symmetric about $t=1/2$. Does this help visualise better?